# How to navigate to the current cursor location in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, keyboard-shortcuts

What's the fastest way to return to the current cursor location in Visual Studio? After I've scrolled up or down in the code editor I want to quickly return to the cursor location without visually searching.

A roundabout technique is to navigate to the previous location then back to the current location: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>. I'd like to do the same thing with a single keyboard shortcut. I've tried <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>. That takes me back but it highlights a bunch of code which could lead to an accidental overwrite.

Comment: Just use the arrows keys... left , right. it will jump back.

Comment: Awesome. Never thought of that! Enter that as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: You can you Ctrl+G this will take you to the line where the Cursor is.
The full shorcuts list is here http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2017/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you only need to use arrow keys (right,left up or down) that's it :)